# remap Spring MVC dispatcherServlet via annotations to some other path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering if it would be possible via annotations remap Spring MVC dispatcherServlet from "/" to some other path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you mean by "remap Spring MVC DispatcherServlet" via annotation, but if you mean creating the `DispatcherServlet` in `Java` without using `XML`, you can use the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` if you are using `Spring 3.2+`.

Application class that register and initialize the dispatcher servlet :

```
public class Application extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
         return new Class<?>[]{ApplicationConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

The configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("foo.bar")
public class ApplicationConfig {
    //Add beans if needed
}
```